# XML to Json conversion with HTML string data

Tags: json, xml, json.net, xml-serialization, json-deserialization

I have XML documents that I am trying to convert to Json but some of the string fields have HTML tags in them (from copy/paste of text fields from Word documents). The source XML looks like this:

```
<my:Request_Description>
    <html xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <div>test</div>
    </html>
</my:Request_Description>
```

When `JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode` is called the Json ends up as this:

```
"Request_Description": {
    "html": {
        "@xml:space": "preserve",
        "@xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
        "#significant-whitespace": [
            "\r\n      ",
            "\r\n"
        ],
        "div": "test"
    }
}
```

I tried to just declare the field as a string but when calling `deserializeobject` the error is `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value`.

Is there something I should do on the serializexmlnode to make the Json result different? Or is there something I can do on the deserializeobject to have it ignore the HTML tag?

Ideally the json would be something like below but I assume some escape characters would need to be included for the quote marks. The main point being that HTML tags do NOT denote a separate node but instead are part of the value for the node. I started looking into XSLT and thought that might be an option.

```
{
    "Request_Description": "<html xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><div>test</div></html>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switched to using XDocument and this code worked.

```
    XElement req_desc = newxdoc.Root.Element("Request_Description");
    if (req_desc != null)
    {
        XElement replacenode = new XElement(req_desc.Name, req_desc.Value);
        req_desc.Parent.Add(replacenode);
        req_desc.Remove();
    }
```